# Potential bug in average handling time calculation

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, flags

We've noticed something odd in the monthly average-handling-time for flags on ServerFault. It has gone decidedly up in the last week or so, even though the 'daily' handling times have  been sub-hour. Something is up, here.

Our current theory is that when posts that have been flagged a second (or third) time previously gain another flag (perhaps an Off Topic close three months ago earns a please-delete), when that post gets handled again, the handling time of both the previously-handled flag and the new flag gets included into the average. It would explain the inflation we're seeing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, it looks like there is a glitch with deletions due to votes (spam etc), which is not recording the flags as deleted correctly. I will investigate why.

---

The query responsible for this has been taken outside, flogged mercilessly until it agreed to co-operate, then dragged back inside and made to do the washing up. When it has finished that (and in the next deploy), it'll resume it's place.

For info, your average time (with the fix) over the last 30 days is 43 minutes. Good effort!

Comment: Thank you! New mods, you know how it goes.